# Why do I get different answers when taking the same limit?

Tags: calculus

$$f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+10x}-x$$

1)
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x^2(1+\frac{10}{x})}-x = \lim_{x \to \infty}|x| - x = \lim_{x \to \infty} x - x = 0$$

2) If I rationalize it, I get the answer 5.

I've used method #1 several times and it's never failed me.  What's wrong? Why is it wrong this time?

Comment: Your second method basically amounts to evaluating the first limit before evaluating the whole limit. You can't do this when you have $\infty - \infty$.

Comment: If we only know $u$ is big and $v$ is big we know nothing about $u-v$.

Comment: A valid workaround is to write $\sqrt{x^2+10x}-x = x(\sqrt{1+10/x} - 1) = \frac{\sqrt{1+10/x}-1}{\frac{1}{x}}$. Then you can change variables to $u=1/x$ to get $\lim_{u \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{1+10u}-1}{u}$, which is just the derivative of $\sqrt{1+10x}$ at $0$. This is more or less the same as rationalizing, of course, since rationalizing is how you would compute the derivative of the square root in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first equality doesn't make sense. This is what you (presumably) did:

$$\lim_{x\to a} (f(x)g(x)-h(x)) = \lim_{x\to a} (f(x)\cdot\lim_{x\to a} [g(x)]-h(x))$$

Now, consider $a=0, f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}, g(x)=x, h(x)=1$

Answer (score 2):

your first method omit some steps，and not correct，if ${x \to \infty}$,then$$\lim_{x \to \infty} (\sqrt{x^2(1+\frac{10}{x})}-x) \neq \lim_{x \to \infty}\sqrt{x^2(1+\frac{10}{x})} - \lim_{x \to \infty}x $$ $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\sqrt{x^2(1+\frac{10}{x})} \neq \lim_{x \to \infty}\sqrt{x^2} \centerdot \lim_{x \to \infty}\sqrt{1+\frac{10}{x}}$$